# Square POS integration into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, square

I've looked at a few WordPress themes that I want to use to make a website for my soccer club.

We had Square POS integrated into the old one, I was wondering how easy/difficult it is to integrate the POS system into a WordPress theme, and where would I look to find how to do it?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what Square POS is, please provide a reference link to what you are asking.

Comment: It's essentially a Point of Sale system that we use to take payments from players for stuff like registration and kits, etc.

Comment: It may be possible to formulate a URL that you can activate from the browser, see https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/setup-web#step-3-add-code-to-initiate-a-transaction-from-your-mobile - haven't done it myself, let me know how you go